# HTACCESS image caching rule that checks the image modification time

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

I'm serving images two different ways:

1. Using a PHP script for profile pictures for example
2. By pointing to them directly, for icons and backgrounds for example

I'm in the process of handling their caching properly, and i'm totally new to this.

For the PHP script, i'm just adding a `Last-Modified` header to the response, and delivering a `304 status code` if it's called again, **if the file hasn't changed** (using `filemtime()`).

For direct accesses, i'm using HTACCESS, but every rule i saw so far doesn't allow me to do the same as in my PHP script (checking if the file has changed, then serving a 304 or the file itself).

Here's the HTACCESS rule i'm planning to use:

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# cache images/pdf docs for 10 days
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
  Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

From what i understand, **the only way of updating a cached image is to rename it.** Does someone know a way around it? By checking the image's last modification date for instance?

Comment: The only way is indeed to change the url. You could just add a versionnumber to the url, so it becomes something like `/images/sample.jpg?v=2`. You could use some rewrite rules to make prettier urls like `/images/v2/sample.jpg`. You'll have to be careful to not change the url if the image hasn't changed, because the new url will not work with the 304.

Comment: Have you tried [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gumbo pointed out, "Apache should already do that for static files".
And that's true, Apache does that, so that kind of stuff works fine:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

ps: Sorry @Gumbo, but i asked you to change your answer so that i can accept it, but you wouldnt do it and i had to close that question eventually, so.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html), if available:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
  ExpiresDefault "modification plus 10 days"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I read the doc you pointed me to, but what i understand is that using the directive you wrote will just set the expiration date to the file last modification date + 10 days, am i right?

Comment: Then that's not what i was looking for :( I guess you don't know of something like that but that doesn't answer to use the cached version of a file if it's been modified during these 10 days?

Comment: Then what should answer the server instead? What exactly are you looking for? A response is fresh within 10 days after modification and then what?

Comment: Well that's what i'm explaining in the question, i handle cache two different ways: using PHP, and using Apache (thus htaccess, since i don't have access to httpd.conf). My PHP scripts always answers a 304 (=tells to use the cache), EXCEPT when the file is different than the one in the cache. But i don't know any way to do the same with Apache, i only know what a way (the one you wrote) to make a cached file expire after some time, not right after it's been modified. I don't know if i made myself clear enough :/

Comment: Apache should already do that for static files. Is there some specific reason that this doesn’t work for you?

Comment: I was persuaded it wasn't, only from what i read.. Let me run some tests, and i'll come back to you.

Comment: Alright, could you just edit your answer to match your last comment so that i can accept your answer? Apache is effectively answering with the new file instead of a 304 if it's updated, so i guess my question was dumb. Thanks for your help! (Another thing, i would advise you not to use the rule you wrote -modification plus 10 days- since if the file is older than 10 days, the cached version will never be used, even though it should be)

Comment: mod_expires does only implement the [expiration model](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13.2). You would need to use a different validation if you want to prevent that. That’s where you can use mod_headers to send additional *Cache-Control* directives.

Comment: Yes, i went up with that, if you want to put it in your answer: `<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion alone or together with your current configuration?

Comment: Alone, it worked at te time i tested but the above worked too and seemed less bug prone

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with PHP should do apache automatically for static files. It will set the Last-Modified header and respond with 304 if it will find if-Modified-since in the request. This is done automatically and has nothing to do with caching. It will not prevent repeated requests to your server, it will just save you bandwidth (and loading times for user) when the file is not modified by returning just 304 info instead of the whole file.

To prevent those repeated requests to your server, browser (and proxy servers) has to do some caching. You can control the caching either via HTTP headers or for HTML also via META tags. When you specify that the file is cacheable for 1 week, browser won't try to contact your server for 1 week (although most browsers are set to revalidate cache entries on first access after startup).

So you will either live with the possibility that some users will use old cached copy for some time (depends on the expiry header) or you must change your URL as Gerben suggested. Only then you can be 100% sure that everyone will get the new version (this is important for javascript as having some of the js files old and some new can make very strange errors). Nowadays almost every high performance website uses the `file.ext?v=3` approach, so that they can set the expiry header to large values like 6 months.

Comment: Actually, HTML meta tags will not be scraped by proxies, so it's better to use headers